# What's the rationle behind "directory mask" in smb.conf?

Tags: permissions, samba

Let's say have a directory 'myshare' with SGID enabled, just for testing I've set in smb.conf:

```
[myshare]
        comment = myshare
        path = /var/lib/samba/myshare
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0770
```

As far I understand the directories should be created with 0770, but it don't, they are created with 2770 anyway. So what it's the purporse of that parameter, if it is ignored? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you creating the files on the client or on the server itself? If the former, did you restart the service after changing `smb.conf`?

Comment: Yup, of course I did.